# Fluidbox: fluidbox-wrap Taller Than Image

Tags: javascript

I'm using [Fluidbox](https://github.com/terrymun/Fluidbox) for the first time, but I've noticed that the `fluidbox-wrap` element's `height` seems to be around 4px bigger than the image I'm using.

I've created a CodePen of the issue I'm having [over here](http://codepen.io/realph/pen/pvwQod).

Does anyone know how to fix this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That is because both your anchor and image element are `inline-block` by default—changing them to block level elements will fix that issue :)